# I'm using verify(mockito) here. Is it the correct way of testing my service?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a question related to Unit Testing in Spring boot. I have a simple application of user management that does basic crud operations about User. I use a service that gets called inside the controller depending upon the end point. So for example :

for url =   "/createUser" - ***service.createUser*** gets called and takes care of all the activity (checking user already exists or not, and other exception handling) and eventually adds the user in database.

Now I'm to Unit test this service in case of creating the user, following is my code:

```
@Test
    void testRegisterUser() {       
        Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();        
        signUpRequest.setCustomername("s");
        signUpRequest.setCustomerid("1s");
        signUpRequest.setCustomername("custsomername");
        signUpRequest.setDescription("customser description");
        signUpRequest.setEmail("customser@mail.com");   
        signUpRequest.setPassword("12s3");
        signUpRequest.setRole(roles);  
        service.createUser(signUpRequest);
        verify(repository, times(1)).save(any(UserModel.class));
    }
```

In the end all I'm doing is calling the service's method to create the user. I have mocked this service and repository. And at the last line, I'm verifying that the repository has been called at once or not.

What I want to understand am I doing it the right way? Is it the right way to test it? My Senior wants assert over here, but what's the point of assertEquals if ***createUser*** doesnt return any value since I'm not doing Integration Testing, There is no db in here. All I'm testing here is my logic and mimicking the behavior. I would appreciate a thorough answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the code for your repository as well , it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However it seems you have written a right test case (Which covers all the lines of service) but using this approach you might miss some use cases like -

1. If some exception occurs down while saving the data from SQL level, and thrown to service , even then your test case will verify (As the method is called), and you would not be able to cover this scenario.

Now assuming you have used **CrudRepository<T,ID> ,  S save(S entity)** method.
It returns the object after operation is done, and throws exception in case above.
You should actually mock the repository and set the return , and then assert for positive case, and expect the exception for the case I mentioned earlier.

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience here are some guidelines on automated testing -

1. At any point in time, we try to have 100% automated test coverage. It can be using integration testing or unit testing. If a scenario or functionality can be tested using unit testing then I prefer to pick unit testing over integrated testing due to the following reasons -

- Unit tests are always quick to run
- Ideally unit tests should not depend on external dependencies such as databases or external service or special infrastructure. Each unit test case should be focused on testing the smallest possible functionality. This will ensure that you can run unit test cases at any point in time without depending on external dependencies. We should mock all other dependencies as part of unit testing.
- Managing unit test cases are a lot easier than managing integrated test cases for any future functionality changes.

2. Sometimes it is difficult to have 100% test coverage with only unit test cases in those scenarios we try to have integrated test cases. If your application is having UI interaction then those can't be tested with only unit test cases so we will cover those scenarios with integrating test cases.
3. Let's take an example - If your service method is having two different possible scenarios and your method is invoked by the user action over the browser. As part of the integration testing, you can cover one scenario which takes care of the UI functionality. The other scenario in your service method can be covered using just unit test cases. This will ensure your entire functionality can be tested.
4. Ideally we try to achieve 100% automated test coverage but in some scenarios, we try to avoid it when the engineering/infrastructure cost exceeds the value provided by an automated test case. It is a conscious trade-off.
5. Some teams may not prioritize to have 100% test coverage due to a lack of resources as well.

Now coming back to your scenario, without looking at your service method code it is difficult to give you a satisfactory answer. Your unit test case is only checking if your service method is making a call to the repository method called only once or not. If that covers the entire functionality of your application then you are all good. There is no wrong or correct approach as long as your unit cases cover the most functionality and easy to maintain then you are good.

Answer (score 1):

> My Senior wants assert over here, but what's the point of assertEquals if createUser doesnt return any value since I'm not doing Integration Testing, There is no db in here. All I'm testing here is my logic and mimicking the behavior.

At the moment you only test that the `save` method of the repository is called with some `UserModel`. This means that you don't know if the `UserModel` does contain all the values it should. Maybe there is a mapping bug in your service so that the `request` model's values are not correctly transformed and mapped to the `UserModel` or you introduce such a bug later and your test will not show it. I guess that is what the senior means when he says that he wants assertions.

What you can do is to use mockito's [`ArgumentCaptor`](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html). It helps you to get the `UserModel` that was passed to the repository so that you can make assertions. E.g.

```
service.createUser(signUpRequest);

ArgumentCaptor<UserModel> userModelCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(UserModel.class);
verify(repository, times(1)).save(userModelCaptor.capture());

UserModel userModel = userModelCaptor.getValue();

// Make assertions - I assume that your UserModel has an accessor method for email
assertEquals("customser@mail.com", userModel.getEmail());
```